# c++ string concatenate solution

Tags: c++, string

why this code is not working ? the error message :main.cpp:147:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘fin’

```
   string file;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.clear();

    cout << "\n\t--------------------------------Enter Person's name then surname to display------";
    cin>>file;

    file +=".txt"
    fin.open(file.c_str());

    char word[50];
    fin>>word;
    while(fin.good()){


        cout << word << " ";
        fin >> word;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which one is line 147? Seems like there's a lot of code you are not showing

Comment: The error says it all: you forgot a `;` on line 146 (since the error is on line 147). Meh.

Comment: The error message actually tells you **exactly** what the error is.

Comment: its  fin.open(file.c_str());

Comment: I would start to look at line 147, but you're going to get an exception when you try and use the `(*l).SetName(name)` line, as you never pointed `l` to anything.

Comment: error msg line is  fin.open(file.c_str());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are missing a `;` after `file +=".txt"`.

```
string file;
ifstream fin;
fin.clear();

cout << "\n\t--------------------------------Enter Person's name then surname to display------";
cin>>file;

file +=".txt";
fin.open(file.c_str());

char word[50];
fin>>word;
while(fin.good()){


    cout << word << " ";
    fin >> word;
}


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need a semi-colon at the end of this line:

```
file +=".txt"
```

That should fix the error.

Comment: thank you. I dont know why Netbeans shows the wrong line as the error source.

Comment: @BaturayE.H.AHMAD Netbeans is not the problem. Missing `;` always shows up on the next line, not on the line it is actually missing. Learn how the C++ syntax/parser works and this will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi colon in the line below.

```
file +=".txt"   <-------- put a semi colon HERE
    fin.open(file.c_str());
```